# Boot stuck at rc-local.service

Tags: raspbian, boot

I setup Rasbian on a 32GB sd card and inserted it into Raspberry Pi 3 Model B(V1.2). When I swtch on the Raspberry Pi, It's boot stuck at `rc-local.service`. First I tried Rasbian. I flashed the image without any modifications. Then I erased SD card and put a Windows IoT image.

It get power from a power adapter(5v = 3000mA)
Keyboard and mouse is connected.(When I removed the keyboard and mouse and switched on the raspberry pi, it stuck at `polkit.service`)
How can I overcome from this?[image]

Comment: Do you flashed the image without modifications? It is known that it works if don't use a broken RasPi.

Comment: Yes, I flashed the image without any modifications. Then I put a image of Windows IoT, it also gives error(lbue screen errors). It seems there is a issue in Raspberry Pi 3

Comment: I do not understand. I haven't used Windows IoT yet so I don't know anything about it. What I understand is that you flashed one of these [Raspbian Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) images and then put an image of Windows IoT on it. How do you put that image onto the flashed Raspbian SD Card?

Comment: First I tried Rasbian. Then I erased SD card and put a Windows IoT image.

Comment: If you booted unmodified Raspbian and it stuck at rc-local.service then your Raspberry Pi is broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you booted unmodified Raspbian and it stuck at rc-local.service then your Raspberry Pi or your SD Card is broken. Try another RasPi or another SD Card. Use another flash program. Verify checksum of the downloaded Raspbian image.